# Cordova / Phonegap iOS Safari and speech synthesis wont work

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, speech-synthesis

I am using this simple code in cordova:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {

    function talk () {
      /*var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('jee wiz, you are so funny !');
      /*msg.rate = 1; msg.pitch = 5; msg.lang ="en_EN";*/
      /*speechSynthesis.speak(msg);*/
      var u = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
      u.text = 'Hello World';
      u.lang = 'en-US';
      u.rate = 1.2;
      u.onend = function(event) { console.log('Finished in ' + event.elapsedTime + ' seconds.'); }
      speechSynthesis.speak(u);
    }
    var element  =  document.getElementById('button');
    element.addEventListener('click', function () {
      talk();
    });
    }, false);
```

So actually talk(); returns this error in console : `Speech initialization error: 2147483665`

and then the app looks crashed/frezzed and I can't do anything on the page.

It's strange speech synthesis looks supported on ios http://caniuse.com/#search=speech

What's wrong and why I can't get talk(); if I trigger the click on the button?

**NB: I am testing on ios simulator with ios 7/8**

Comment: `function talk()` needs to be created outside of the eventlistener

Comment: @DawsonLoudon i get the same error in console also if i move the talk function outside of deviceready listner :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iOS 8 simulator doesn't support text-to-speech. Try it on a real device.

Also move your function talk out of device ready event listener.